# user communication with open source

Tags: project-management, collaboration, software-use

regarding using/developing, reporting issues (bugs/usability issues) or requesting new feature, 
what are the obstacles in front of users to let their voice be heard?

what mechanisms and communication channel you wish to have?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean? This is rather an open ended question and what you ask is not crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think the obstacles are much less than you'd encounter with a closed-source project.  For the ones I'm involved with, the main obstacle is that the user needs to subscribe to a mailing list, a forum, or to sourceforge or github to communicate bug reports and feature requests (when we allowed anonymous requests we just got a huge amount of SPAM and the legitimate submissions got lost in the noise).  But we watch things like Stack Exchange and even Twitter as well.